# show iphone badge count when user logged in

Tags: iphone

I have a web application which runs in native browser control of iphone. I want to show badge count when user login into site and remove once logged out. Similar to iphone app for gmail.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Care to try again?

Comment: You can see Gmail iphone app - http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8

Comment: Are you want to show badge count on tabbar item?

Comment: perhaps this will help you. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5156-uitabbarcontroller-how-set-badgevalue-certain-tab.html

Comment: I want to show badge count on Application Icon. Similar to gmail iphone app when clicked on application icon it will prompt for login and once user login successfully it will should unread email count as badge on application icon.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple
just make a hidden div with a id into the webpage and when user logged in put the value you want into that div and after that in webview finished method get the value from this

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('DIV_ID').text"];
```

Comment: How can I this count keep updated? chances like user may not refresh page after login. But count may change based on updates received for user.

Comment: We can do it using Ajax. But only concern with Ajax is will it keep running when application is minimized. I am looking for option if I can pass on the token to native application once I login.